# Related almost primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Do there exist positive integers $w, x, y, z$ and an infinite set $A$ such that for all $a \in A$, $a$ is a $w$-almost prime and $b = y \cdot a + z$ is an $x$-almost prime?  With $(w,x,y,z) = (1,1,2,1)$ this is the Germain prime conjecture, and with $(w,x,y,z) = (1,1,1,2)$ it is the twin primes conjecture, but I wonder if anything can be demonstrated with other parameters?

Comment: What's a $w$-almost prime?

Comment: @GerryMyerson See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_prime). (A number is $\omega$-almost prime if it has precisely $\omega$ prime factors, counted with multiplicity. So a prime number is a $1$-almost prime number.)

Comment: Well, it's known that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is either a prime or a product of two primes. I'm not sure whether it's known that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ has precisely 2 prime factors, counted with multiplicity. A good book on The Sieve Method might have some answers to your question.